# Doubt in the simplification.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following equation where $\mathbf k=(k_1,\dots,k_n) \in \mathbb{Z}_+^n$ and $l|\mathbf k$ means that $l | k_i$ for each $i$.

[image]

[image]

Assume that $m_0(\eta(-))$, $m_1(\eta(-))$ and $|\pi_{\mathbf k}^G(q)[q]|$ are functions from $\mathbb{Z}_+^n$ to $\mathbb N$. I want find $m_0(\eta(-))$, $m_1(\eta(-))$ interms of  $\pi_{\mathbf k}^G(q)$ using Mobius inversion formula.

Kindly share your thoughts.

Thank you.

PS: Miguel has given a nice answer. But I think using Mobius inversion formula the resultant expression will be much simpler. This is my intuition but couldn't work out the details. For the first equation, I got the answer

[image]

I guess, for the second equation the answer will be $m_1(\eta(\textbf k))$ is equal to

[image].

is it correct?

Comment: If $gcd(k_1,...,k_n)=1$ your formula gives $m_1(\eta (k))=-|\pi_k^G(q)[q]|$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $g.c.d(k_{1},...,k_{n})=1$, then $$m_{1}(\eta (k)) = |\pi_{k}^G(q)[q]|$$

Now for example if $g.c.d(k_{1},...,k_{n})=2$, we have $$m_{1}(\eta (k))-\frac{1}{2}m_{1}(\eta (\frac{k}{2}))=m_{1}(\eta (k))-\frac{1}{2}|\pi_{\frac{k}{2}}^G(q)[q]|$$ therefore $m_{1}(\eta (k))=\frac{1}{2}|\pi_{\frac{k}{2}}^G(q)[q]|+|\pi_{k}^G(q)[q]|$.

Let $d=g.c.d(k_{1},...,k_{n})$. If $d$ is prime then $m_{1}(\eta (k))=\frac{(-1)^{d+2}}{d}|\pi_{\frac{k}{d}}^G(q)[q]|+|\pi_{k}^G(q)[q]|$.

Since we know the formula for $d$ prime I believe it should be possible to induct a general formula but it becomes quite complicated for me.

Edit:

Let $d$ denote $gcd(k)$ and $d_i$ denote $gcd(\frac{k}{i})$. From back substituting one can get $$m_{1}(\eta (k))=|\pi_{k}^G(q)[q]|+\sum_{l|d}\frac{(-1)^{l+2}}{l}m_{1}(\eta (\frac{k}{l}))=|\pi_{k}^G(q)[q]|+\sum_{l|d}\frac{(-1)^{l+2}}{l}(|\pi_{\frac{k}{l}}^G(q)[q]|+\sum_{i|d_l}\frac{(-1)^{i+2}}{i}m_1(\eta(\frac{k}{l\cdot i})))=|\pi_{k}^G(q)[q]|+\sum_{l|d}\frac{(-1)^{l+2}}{l}(|\pi_{\frac{k}{l}}^G(q)[q]|+\sum_{i|d_l}\frac{(-1)^{i+2}}{i}(|\pi_{\frac{k}{l\cdot i}}^G(q)[q]|+\sum_{j|d_{i\cdot l}}\frac{(-1)^{j+2}}{j}m_{1}(\eta (\frac{k}{l \cdot i}))))$$

Note that we can keep substituting until we get $m_{1}(\eta (\frac{k}{d}))=|\pi_{\frac{k}{d}}^G(q)[q]|$

$$m_{1}(\eta (k))=|\pi_{k}^G(q)[q]|+\sum_{l|d}\frac{(-1)^{l+2}}{l}(|\pi_{\frac{k}{l}}^G(q)[q]|+\sum_{i|d_l}\frac{(-1)^{i+2}}{i}(|\pi_{\frac{k}{l\cdot i}}^G(q)[q]|+\sum_{j|d_{i\cdot l}}\frac{(-1)^{j+2}}{j}(...|\pi_{\frac{k}{d}}^G(q)[q]|))...)$$

Comment: Can you please explain to me, how you got the equation when gcd = 2? Thanks.

Comment: @GA316 the only numbers that divide $k$ are $1$ and $2$, and the only number that divides $\frac{k}{2}$ is $1$, the equation comes from substituting $m_1(\eta (\frac{k}{2})) = |\pi_{\frac{k}{2}}^G(q)[q]|$

Comment: Thanks. Does the final expression involve the Mobius function? Can we use Mobius inversion formula?

Comment: @GA316 I am not sure, the Mobius inversion formula involves arithmetic functions and $k$ is not an integer here, but I probably don't have enough experience to comment on that.

Comment: again thanks a lot. :)

Comment: @GA316 sorry the last formula is not quite right, I will look into it as soon as I can

Comment: @GA316 I have edited again, should be alright.